# Convergence of the alternating series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^nx^{3n}}{n!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying determine the set of values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following series converges.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^nx^{3n}}{n!}}
$$

But I am yet to understand how to work with these types of series. For what I may understand (if I interpreter correctly) is to determine whether the modulus values of the sum increases or decreases, find a upper or lower limit and the character of that limit would determine that of the sum. Is that correct?

How do I proceed?

Comment: All of them. Such series is just $e^{-x^3}-1$ (an entire function).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But what would be the proceedure in determining this?

Comment: Root test, ratio test, …

Comment: Given $e^{x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ (one of the fundamental identities in Calculus) and the fact that $e^x$ is entire, you just have to replace $x$ with $-x^3$ and drop the $n=0$ term. Entireness is preserved.

Comment: The [ratio-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) is the simplest way to establish convergence here. Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$ where $a_n =\frac{(-1)^n x^{3n}}{n!}$ and show that it's $<1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{3n}}{n!}\right|=\frac{\left|x\right|^{3n}}{n!}
$$

Then you can use the d'Alembert critera to show it converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

$${\displaystyle e^{x}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}}=1+x+{\frac {x^{2}}{2!}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3!}}+\cdots }$$
$${\displaystyle e^{x}-1=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n!}}}$$
now let $x=-x^3$ to get
$${\displaystyle e^{-x^3}-1=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {-x^{3n}}{n!}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^nx^{3n}}{n!}}$$
that means it converges for all values of $x$